# Yii2 как выбрать данные из связанных таблиц?

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Есть таблица рецептов(rec), таблица ингредиентов(ing), и таблица связей(rec_ing).
Таблица rec_ing имеет вид:

```
id | rec_id | ing_id
```

Соответственно рецепт может быть связан с несколькими ингредиентами, а каждый ингредиент может быть использован в разных рецептах.

Вопрос: 
Имея список ингредиентов необходимо получить список рецептов которые можно приготовить из этих ингредиентов.

Например: 
Рецепт сока может содержать 2 ингредиента - яблоко и груша, а рецепт хлеба - мука и молоко.
В случае если мы имеем 3 ингредиента (яблоко, груша, мука) и выгружаем рецепты по этим ингредиентам, то должны получить только рецепт сока, так как для хлеба у нас не хватает ингредиента мука.

Как это реализовать в Yii2?

Answer (score 1):

Эту проблему можно решить многими способами.
Вот один из вариантов:

```
$ing_names = ['яблоко', 'груша', 'мука'];
$ings = Ing::find()->where(['name' => $ing_name])->indexBy('id')->all();
$ing_ids = array_keys($ings);

$try_rec_ids = RecIng::find()->select('rec_id')->where(['ing_id' => $ing_ids])->column();
$try_recs = Rec::find()->where(['id' => $try_rec_ids])->with('rec_ings')->all();

$recs = [];
foreach ($try_recs as $try_rec) {
    $ok = true;
    foreach ($try_rec->rec_ings as $rec_ing) {
        if (!in_array($rec_ing->ing_id, $ing_ids)) {
            $ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($ok) {
        $recs[] = $try_rec;
    }
}
```

Comment: Решение рабочее. Только думаю, что все это должно происходить в модели.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо создать функции аналогично [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data):

```
class Data extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $id;
    public $rec_id;
    public $ing_id;
}

class Ingredient extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $id;

    public function getRecipes()
    {
        $entries = $this->hasMany(Data::className(), ['id' => 'ing_id']);
        $recipes = array();

        foreach($entries as $entry)
            $recipes[] = Recipe::find()->where('id' => $entry);

        return $recipes;
    }
}

class Recipe extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $id;

    public function getIngredients()
    {
        $entries = $this->hasMany(Data::className(), ['id' => 'rec_id']);
        $ingredients = array();

        foreach($entries as $entry)
            $ingredients[] = Ingredient::find()->where('id' => $entry);

        return $ingredients;
    }
}

$recipe = Recipe:find()->where(['name' => 'Борщ'])->all();
$ingredients = $recipe->ingredients; // массив ингредиентов для борща

$ingredient = Ingredient::find()->where(['name' => 'Лук'])->all();
$recipesWith = $ingredient->recipes; // массив рецептов, в которых есть лук
```

Comment: Это не совсем то что нужно. В данном случае выводятся все рецепты содержащие указанные ингредиенты. А необходимо получить следующее:

Comment: Имея список ингредиентов выгрузить только те рецепты, в которых используются только данный набор ингредиентов. Например для яичницы нужны яйца и соль. Если мы имеем из ингредиентов только яйца, то соответственно приготовить яичницу не сможем. Значит этот рецепт нам не подходит.

Comment: В таком случае вам надо добавить следующее:

$myIngredients = array(Ingredient::find()->where('name' => 'Яйцо')->id, Ingredient::find()->where('name' => 'Соль')->id);
$myRecipes = Recipe::find()->where(['and', ['ing_id' => $myIngredients]]);